# How to get Spyder to recognize the setup.cfg file on Windows 10

Tags: spyder

I'm trying to turn off the ignore max-line-length warnings in Spyder.
This question was answered in another post, but I can't seem to get Spyder to read the config.sys file
[pep8]
max-line-length = 120

I've tried putting it in my current working directory, Python27, Python27/Scripts.

None of those locations turns off the 79 char warning.

I open my .py file by right clicking on it and choose edit in Spyder.

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally understood the comment from Justin Harris in a previous question.
[Python: How to tell Spyder's style analysis PEP8 to read from a setup.cfg or increase max. line length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426689/python-how-to-tell-spyders-style-analysis-pep8-to-read-from-a-setup-cfg-or-inc)

You should follow these steps:

First, run:

```
import os; os.path.expanduser('~')
```

Then, put your `.pep8` file in the directory that is displayed by the above command.

The contents of the file to make it ignore lines under 120 characters is:

```
[pep8]
max-line-length = 120
```

Comment: Notice, that this method will disable it userwide. The linked question also provides a solution for projectwide disabling.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. Any other suggestions? I'm trying it in the eclilpse environment also.