# Spyder ignores .pycodestyle

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder, pep8, pycodestyle

I am using Spyder v.3.2.8 and I'm trying to modify the Real-time code style analysis. For example, I'd like to set the max-line-length to 99.

I exactly followed what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426689/python-how-to-tell-spyders-style-analysis-pep8-to-read-from-a-setup-cfg-or-inc), i.e. I created a file `.pycodestyle` in the directory resulting from `import os; os.path.expanduser('~')`. The file looks as follows

```
[pycodestyle]
ignore = E226,E302,E41,E501,W503
max-line-length = 99
```

I am aware that ignoring E501 renders `max-line-length` virtually ineffective. However, I still get warnings if the code exceeds the default 79 columns. Am I missing something?

EDIT:

The issue is solved now. All of a sudden, the settings are recognized. A reboot might have helped (OS: Windows 10).

Comment: The `~/.pycodestyle` path also worked for me (Windows 10, Spyder 3.3.2, Python 3.7)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I have resolved it by creating a file `~/.config/pycodestyle` (without a dot and inside `~/.config`) instead of `~/.pycodestyle`, according to the official website:

- https://pep8.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#configuration

Comment: Confirm for Spyder 3.3.6. Had to restart Spyder.